# How to disable logging and monitoring service in GKE service in GCP Cloud via terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a terraform code to enable logging and monitoring service in GKE service of GCP console via terrraform, But the GCP console by default enables the logging and monitoring services. Now I am trying to disable the logging and monitoring service, I dont see any code or keyword to disable it, anyone can help me here?

```
 resource "google_container_cluster" "test" {
  logging_service = "logging.googleapis.com/kubernetes"
  monitoring_service = "monitoring.googleapis.com/kubernetes"
  }
###how to disable this? I tried with
 resource "google_container_cluster" "test" {
   logging_service = ""
   monitoring_service = ""
  }
```

But not working!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link, try leaving the `monitoring_config` block off completely and set `monitoring_service` to "none" and see if that resolves your issue :

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/10308

From `Terraform` documentation :

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster

```
monitoring_service - (Optional) The monitoring service that the cluster should write metrics to.
```